# Executing a PHP file from iOS app and refreshing label text

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

In my app I need to include a button action to update the value of a MySQL field in a remote server. When the user taps on the button, the app should add 1 to a field value.

The MySQL value is shown in a UILabel.

I have written the PHP file to make the update to the database.

In my viewController I am getting the id field to be passed to the PHP file.

This is the button action that performs the value update:

```
- (IBAction)votarAction:(id)sender {
    //URL definition where php file is hosted
    int categoriaID = [[detalleDescription objectForKey:@"idEmpresa"] intValue];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", categoriaID];
    NSLog(@"ID EMPRESA %@",string);
    NSMutableString *ms = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/cambiarvaloracionempresa.php?id="];
    [ms appendString:string];
    // URL request
    NSLog(@"URL = %@",ms);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ms]];
    //URL connection to the internet
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}
```

What I need is that after tapping on the button, and the field value is updated, to show the new value at the UILabel.
Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good way do it:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domai.queue", 0);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    int categoriaID = [[detalleDescription objectForKey:@"idEmpresa"] intValue];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", categoriaID];
    NSLog(@"ID EMPRESA %@",string);
    NSMutableString *ms = [[NSMutableString alloc] 
                                      initWithString:@"http://url.php?id="];
    [ms appendString:string];

    // URL request
    NSLog(@"URL = %@",ms);
    NSURLRequest *request = 
                      [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ms]];

    //URL connection to the internet
    NSData *responseData = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                    initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"responseData= %@",responseData);//["34"]

    //Parse JSON
    NSMutableDictionary  * json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                               JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                          options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                            error: &error];

    NSString *labelValue = (NSString*) [json objectAtIndex:0];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //update your UIlabel dataLabel
        dataLabel.text = labelValue;
    });    
});
```

You should make the request and return the JSON in a background thread, then update the UILabel in the main queue.

Comment: Thank you meda, I will try your code, I guess it will work, but I have a question: what is the function of the domain at the first line?

Comment: its just an identifier of that queue, just if you need to track it or find it. Just like you name your application using reverse domain name.

Comment: And finally, what the PHP file is doing is updating the value in the database and echoing an array with only one key with this format: ["34"]. How do I update the label now?

Comment: Your code is working fine, but your logging of responsedata is empty.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add the `%@` you still need help to parse the json?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to pass the value set by the PHP file to the label. I thought responsedata would be the value, but it isn't.

Comment: I edit my answer more I may have some typos it is not tested ;)

Comment: I have included NSError *error = nil; and now the only error is at line NSString *labelValue = (NSString*) [json objectAtIndex:0]; the error is:  No visible @interface for 'NSMutableDictionary' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'

Comment: Ohh change it to NSArray

Comment: I am getting an exception. I think it will be better if I open another question with the final code I have and showing the exception text. Thank you very much for all your time and effort, I have learned a lof from you.